# Responsive CSS options

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a chat to test site. Using `float right` is perfect, because if the screen goes smaller then it moves with it, but the problem with that it's not "not enough right" for me. Is there any other responsive ways to get the chat more right? I am using bootstrap

Here is the chat HTML code:

```
    <div class="chat pull-right" style="width: 30%">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Chat</h3></div>
            <div class="chat-messages panel-body">
                <div class="chat-user">
                    <div class="chat-username">James</div>
                    <div class="chat-message">This is a test</div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-user">
                    <div class="chat-username">David</div>
                    <div class="chat-message">This is a test</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want have your chat box, example if if want to have chat options always on right corner or always on half height of display, you can use position absolute and z-index for that. PS what mean: "not enough right"? Can you add some screen shot or maybe example on bootply or fiddle.